# I can't catch key event when korean language is edited in text box of android webview

Tags: webview, textbox

I can't catch key event when korean language is edited in text box of android webview.
I can catch key event when english character or number key is pressed in text box of android webview. But multicode language like korean language don't cause key event.
How can I catch multicode language key event in the webview